# Creating link to an url of Flask app in jinja2 template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In my Flask app, I have a view which displays a post

```
@post_blueprint.route('/post/<int:year>/<int:month>/<title>')
def get_post(year,month,title):
    # My code
```

To display the last 10 entries, I have following view:

```
@post_blueprint.route('/posts/')
def get_all_posts():
    # My code
    return render_template('p.html',posts=posts)
```

Now when I display the last 10 posts, I want to convert the title of a post into a hyperlink.
Currently I have to do the following in my jinja template to achieve this:

```
<a href="/post/{{year}}/{{month}}/{{title}}">{{title}}</a>
```

Is there any way to avoid hard coding the url?

Like `url_for` function which is used to create Flask urls like this:

```
url_for('view_name',**arguments)
```

I have tried searching for one but I,m not able to find it.

Comment: So you'd like to have url_for use kwargs? The only way to do that would be to have posts as a list of dicts. I don't believe there's a way for that to be done without changing your logic in the view first.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I feel like you're asking two questions here but I'll take a shot...

For the posting url you'd do this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('post_blueprint.get_post', year=year, month=month, title=title)}}">
    {{ title }}
</a>
```

To handle static files I'd highly suggest using an asset manager like [Flask-Assets](http://flask-assets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), but to do it with vanilla flask you do:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='[filenameofstaticfile]') }}
```

If you'd like more information I highly suggest you read. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files and http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#url-building

**Edit for using kwargs:**

*Just thought I'd be more thorough...*

If you'd like to use `url_for` like this:

```
{{ url_for('post_blueprint.get_post', **post) }}
```

You have to change your view to something like this:

```
@post_blueprint.route('/posts/')
def get_all_posts():
    models = database_call_of_some_kind # This is assuming you use some kind of model
    posts = []
    for model in models:
        posts.append(dict(year=model.year, month=model.month, title=model.title))
    return render_template('p.html', posts=posts)
```

Then your template code can look like this:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('post_blueprint.get_post', **post) }}">
        {{ post['title'] }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

At this point I would actually create a method on the model so you don't have to turn it into a dict, but going that far is up to you :-).

Comment: What is the `models` type and why we need to turn it into a dict? Can't we pass it to our view and just iterate there?