# Flask url_for() with multiple parameters

Tags: python, html, flask

#### The Problem:

I have an a input button in a form that when its submitted should redirect two parameters , `search_val` and `i`, to a `more_results()` function, (listed below), but I get a type error when wsgi builds.

The error is: `TypeError: more_results() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

html:

```
 <form action="{{ url_for('more_results', past_val=search_val, ind=i ) }}" method=post>
    <input id='next_hutch' type=submit value="Get the next Hunch!" name='action'>
 </form>
```

flask function:

```
@app.route('/results/more_<past_val>_hunches', methods=['POST'])
def more_results(past_val, ind):
    
    if request.form["action"] == "Get the next Hunch!":
        ind += 1 
        queried_resturants = hf.find_lunch(past_val) #method to generate a list
        queried_resturants = queried_resturants[ind]
        return render_template(
                               'show_entries.html', 
                                queried_resturants=queried_resturants, 
                                search_val=past_val,
                                i=ind 
                               )
```

Any idea on how to get past the build error?

#### What I've tried:

[Creating link to an url of Flask app in jinja2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124940/creating-link-to-an-url-of-flask-app-in-jinja2-template)

for using multiple paramters with url_for()

[Build error with variables and url_for in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023488/build-error-with-variables-and-url-for-in-flask?rq=1)

similar build erros

As side note, the purpose of the function is to iterate through a list when someone hits a "next page" button. I'm passing the variable `i` so I can have a reference to keep incrementing through the list. Is there a flask / jinja 2 method that would work better? I've looked into the cycling_list feature but it doesn't seem to able to be used to render a page and then re-render it with `cycling_list.next()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your route doesn't specify how to fill in more than just the one `past_val` arg. Flask can't magically create a URL that will pass two arguments if you don't give it a two-argument pattern.

Answer (score 38):

It's also possible to create routes that support variable number of arguments, by specifying default values to some of the arguments:

```
@app.route('/foo/<int:a>')
@app.route('/foo/<int:a>/<int:b>')
@app.route('/foo/<int:a>/<int:b>/<int:c>')
def test(a, b=None, c=None):
   pass
```

Comment: Is the above answer can be considered as a correct way when dealing with multi-step forms in flask? Such that each step is one argument.

Comment: @plaes This does not work for me. It gives 404 if I don't pass arguments b and c

Answer (score 0):

try to serialize your kwargs with json.dumps() like this

```
<form action="{{ url_for('more_results',kwargs=json.dumps({"past_val":search_val,"ind":i} ) }}" method=post>
```

On the flask side,

```
@app.route('/results/more_<kwargs>_hunches', methods=['POST'])
def more_results(kwargs):
   kwargs = json.loads(kwargs)
   past_val=kwargs['past_val']
   ind = kwargs['in']
```

alternatively, you could use flask.session or flask.g to manage these variables with the context of the session or request eg.
assign the value to a `session['past_val'] = search_val` and use the session attributes anywhere including with Jinja template like so `{{session['past_val']}}`