# Flask -- pass arguments to outgoing url.

Tags: python, flask

Some of my endpoints of my flask api use values from an html form to determine what data to return. I'd like to pass the parameters that I use to generate the data I'm returning back to the URL rendered in the browser. Is there a way to do that with flask?

Example:

```
http://example.com/search
```

On the page, the user types the word "duck" into a search box, hits go, and in addition to the results, Flask returns url showing all the parameters I passed into the api underneath the application... e.g:

```
http://example.com/search?&search_term=duck&page=0&per_page=20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [url_for](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#url-building) to generate the url:

```
from flask import redirect, url_for, request
...
# duck = request.form.get('search_term')
return redirect(url_for('search', search_term=duck, page=0, per_page=20))
...
```

Comment: Currently I'm ending the method with render_template() which has a form, and that form POSTs to a url_for(). I don't seem to be able to pass parameters into the url_for() in the jinja template. Is that expected?

Comment: @kelorek You can use `url_for` in jinja too, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023488/build-error-with-variables-and-url-for-in-flask/15838522#15838522 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124940/creating-link-to-an-url-of-flask-app-in-jinja2-template