# How to pass url as parameter in flask template?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I want to pass the url as parameter in _header.html, so that in future in there is any change arrive then we can change in only through one function, this _header.html is included in base.html, I am new in flask so for I just use `{% urlparameter%` I don't know this right or not. Please tell me how to do that, is we required to write any python function for this?

Here I am using `http://192.168.206.133:5001/metering` In Future this will change, so any good approach to handle such type of case

**_header.html**

```
<h1 class="brand"><a href="http://192.168.206.133:5001/metering"">{% url parameter %}</a></h1>
```

**base.html**

```
<body ng-app="flaskhorizonapp">
    {% block content %}
        <div id="container">
            <div class='topbar'>
                {% include "_header.html" %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124940/creating-link-to-an-url-of-flask-app-in-jinja2-template Might help you

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/templates/

Answer (score 1):

In templates, variable references are encapsulated in `{{` and `}}`, not `{%` and `%}`. So you should change the contents of `_header.html` to:

```
<h1 class="brand"><a href="{{ urlparameter }}">{{ urlparameter }}</a></h1>
```

Now the value of the context variable `urlparameter` can be rendered by the template. Here is a simple Flask app to do that:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('base.html', urlparameter='http://www.stackoverflow.com')

app.debug = True
app.run()
```

So you need to pass the variable `urlparameter` to `render_template()`. Note that I enabled debugging as this will help you find errors such as this during development.

`render_template()` assumes that your templates are located in a subdirectory of the directory containing your flask script. The subdirectory must be named `templates`.

Take a look [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/quickstart/#rendering-templates) for more details.